# How can I dynamically create an instance of a class in java?

Tags: java, casting

I would like to create an object dynamically.

I have the following structure:
1 abstract class and several classes that inherit from the abstract class

```java
abstract public class A {..}


public class B extends A{..}
public class C extends A{..}
```

I have a config file where i want to add a class name, to have the ability to control which class it should be used.

```
# config class name
 classname = B
```

I tried the following, but here I have the problem that I have to cast the result
and I do not know how I can do it dynamically at this point

```java
public class TestClass {

  public A instB;

  public void getInstance(){
    this.instB = Class.forName("B") /*here i put later the config value classname*/
    .getConstructor(String.class)
    .newInstance(new Object[]{"test"});   // <--- How to cast this dynamicly to a class in the config?
  }
}
```

How can I dynamically create an instance of a class?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly confuses you. You call the constructor using `newInstance`, provide your arguments, like `newInstance("test")` and then you have to manually cast, like `(A) Class.forName(...)...`.

Comment: If you insist on casting to the child class: First, get the object. Then check the type using "instance of" and cast.

Comment: Note that `instanceof` is obsolete if `B` extends `A`.

Comment: @Zabuza What do you exactly mean by "obsolete" here?

Comment: @Zabuza it's still good practice to use it, as you can't know for sure whether the string in the configuration is for a class that actually extends `A`, and you may want to handle that before an exception is thrown.

Comment: I agree in that dynamic case. But if it is not coming from external, it would be obsolete. Anyways, not really relevant.

Comment: It would be better to test the loaded class with `isAssignableFrom` before running the constructor, though, rather than use `instanceof`, as the constructor may have unwanted side effects in case it's not the appropriate class.

Comment: @Zabuza if i always cast it to A class,
don't I have the problem if my B class has other methods that are not included in A? or If the methods from A are overwritten in subclasses, is the implementation of A not always used instead of one of the subclasses?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This code snippet is kind of equivalent to `Animal animal = new Dog();`, there isnt really any issue with that. `animal.makeNoise()` will bark.

Comment: yes that was exactly the question.
I was not sure whether if I would upcast  it will lose the functionality from subclass  object B or C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast it to A:

```
instB = (A)Class....newInstance(...);
```

You don't need to know the exact class.

Comment: isn't type of the instance  in that case A? I always need the instance of the class that i define in a config, since it may also have additional methods and members

Comment: No, the real type is not A, it's some class that extends A. If you write Object o = "string", the real type of o is String, not Object. There is a difference beween _declared_ type and _actual_ type.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the point of why you really need to use *reflection*. I would suggest using a simple **strategy pattern**, for example:

Strategy.java

```
public interface Strategy {
    void doWork();
}
```

StrategyA.java

```
public class StrategyA implements Strategy {
    @Override
    public void doWork() {
    }
}
```

Strategy B.java

```
public class StrategyB implements Strategy {
    @Override
    public void doWork() {
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // read the option from a config file
        String option = "B";
        Strategy strategy = createStrategy(option);

        // create a context with the strategy
        MyContext context = new MyContext(strategy);
        context.doWork();

        // config has changed dynamically, change the strategy
        context.useStrategy(new StrategyA());
        context.doWork();
    }

    public static Strategy createStrategy(String strategy) {

        if (strategy.equals("A")) {
            return new StrategyA();
        }

        return new StrategyB();
    }
}
```

MyContext.java

```
public class MyContext {
    Strategy strategy;

    public MyContext(Strategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    public void useStrategy(Strategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    public void doWork() {
        strategy.doWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution could work, but i always have to extend this code whenever i have a new subclass of A. I want to avoid that.