# How to dynamically create an object for an abstract class without casting?

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection, abstract-class, instantiation

I have a abstract class in JAVA and few subclasses. I have a function that returns an instance of one of these subclasses. I don't want to check with few if...else to create an object based on the return type. need to do it dynamically at run time. this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136705/how-can-i-dynamically-create-an-instance-of-a-class-in-java) didn't help me 
The ReplaceExpression is an overloaded function that return different subclasses.

```
 // Expression is abstract class, A and B is subclass\
 // this return me null because i did not make a new object for e1, I know a subclass of Expression
       
   

Expression e1 = ReplaceExpression(1);
Expression e2 = ReplaceExpression("a");

    
    public Expression ReplaceExpression(int i)
    {
    Return new A();
    }
    
    public Expression ReplaceExpression(String s)
    {
    Return new B();
    }
```

I can do it like this but i need cleaner solution:

```
if (ReplaceExpression(x).getClass().getSimpleName() == "A")
Expression e1 = new A();
```

**So my question is: is there anyway I can instantiate a new subclass for my abstract class without hardcoding or casting? something like dynamically or reflection**

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? What does `ReplaceExpression` do?

Comment: Yes this can be done both dynamically and reflectivelt (store a `Supplier<Expression>` of each type in a `Map`, and then lookup the supplier based on whatever you’re using to determine the type; or use reflection in many different ways). But we need more information about how you’re determining what type and why the linked solution didn’t work for you.

Comment: What does `ReplaceExpression` return? If it returns `null`, there would be NPE when you call `getClass()`. If it returns something, just use that return value.

Comment: @Sweeper I just Edited: The replace is a function return one of the subclasses at runtime. based on the input parameter it will return one of the subs. but I dont want to check with lots of codes to cast or instantiate for specific type.

Comment: @zhh I did that, the problem is e1 is abstract class and just returning a subclass makes it NULL, i must instantiate a sub with "new" as a base solution

Comment: I think they mean just `Expression e1 = ReplaceExpression(x);`. But this won’t compile unless you tell the compiler if `x` is an `int` or a `String`, at which point it’s no longer dynamic. Where is `x` coming from and what is its type?

Comment: @BeUndead that's the point. x type is not specific. could be anything, int or string. I just said int or string as easy example. in reality of my code x is a subtype of another class. but just an input parameter. based on this, one of the overloaded "Replace.." is called and different A, or B will return

Comment: You need to be more specific about the exact code flow. As mentioned, most likely you will have some sort of rule that can be connected to a `Supplier<Expression>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this with reflection.

Assume you have `Param` class and `Expression` class:

```java
abstract class Param {
    public abstract Class<? extends Expression> getTargetClass();
}

class Sub1 extends Param {
    @Override
    public Class<? extends Expression> getTargetClass() {
        return A.class;
    }
}

class Sub2 extends Param {
    @Override
    public Class<? extends Expression> getTargetClass() {
        return B.class;
    }
}

class A extends Expression {
    public A() {}
}

class B extends Expression {
    public B() {}
}
```

You need a method to tell you which class you want to create, such as `getTargetClass`.

Then in your `ReplaceExpression` method:

```java
public Expression ReplaceExpression(Param x) throws Exception {        
    Class<? extends Expression> cls = x.getTargetClass();
    Constructor<? extends Expression> con = cls.getConstructor();
    return con.newInstance();
}
```

Although you can do this, it is NOT a good solution, just use if statement:

```java
public Expression ReplaceExpression(Param x) {
    if (x instanceof Sub1)
        return new A();
    if (x instanceof Sub2)
        return new B();
    return null;
}
```

##### UPDATE

It looks like you want to create a new `Expression` according to the returned `Expression`. You can use reflection: (still, NOT recommended)

```java
Class<? extends Expression> cls = ReplaceExpression(x).getClass();
Constructor<? extends Expression> con = cls.getConstructor();
Expression e1 = con.newInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think i didnt explained well. My problem is with this line of code: Expression e1 = ReplaceExpression(x); assume the ReplaceExpression knows what to return. but this code gives me e1 as null because I have to say "e1 = new Expression()" in general to create new object. right? but I cannot cause Expression is abstract class. so the problem is not how to send object from ReplaceExpression. thanks though

Comment: that works for me but I didnt get why you mention not Recommended, thanks

Comment: There are lots of articles about this. Such as [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123956/why-should-i-use-reflection).